# Distribution $\rho(t_{wait})$ given distribution $\rho(t_{gap})$ of time gaps between events

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I want to determine the distribution $\rho(t_{wait})$ given the distribution of time gaps between random events, not necessarily Poisson. Here $t_{wait}\equiv$ **time a random arrival spends waiting until the next event**.

In the case of a *Poisson process*, $$\rho(t_{gap}) = \rho(t_{wait}) = \lambda\exp(- \lambda t)\tag{1}$$

because the process has no memory; it doesn't matter if an event *just occurred*, the times $t_{gap}$ are the same as $t_{wait}$.

However, for a general process, if I know $\rho(t_{gap})$, can I say anything about $\rho(t_{wait})$? It's mean, for instance? If not, what extra information do I need?

**EDIT**: To be clear, the "random arrival" is drawn from a uniform distribution between events.

Comment: Technically you need to define what a "random arrival" is, but you probably have some standard notion in mind for that.

Comment: @Ian Good point. In the classic "waiting for a bus" problem about $t_{gap}$ and $t_{wait}$ for a Poisson process, $t_{wait}$ is just the time that a random arrival at the bus station spends waiting for a bus, while $t_{gap}$ is the time interval between buses. This is the notion of "random arrival" I have in mind. Is that well-defined?

Comment: The question is what's the distribution of arrival times. In the usual bus problem this is assumed uniform, i.e. given two bus arrival times we sample uniformly at random from the interval between them (but otherwise independently of them). Sorry if this is pedantic, but the answer *does* depend on this detail.

Comment: @Ian I appreciate the point. I am assuming uniform distribution between events. Is there anything else I should specify?

Comment: No, now it is clear.